# Can I use t-SNE for checking the goodness of a clustering based on Gower distance matrix?

Tags: clustering, pca, tsne

I am currently working in Python with a dataset with both categorical and continuous variables. The main objective is to do clustering and find how different features help to create the clusters.

This is done with a Hierarchical Clustering  that uses a Gower pre-computed distance matrix (this distance allows to use both categorical and continuous features).

The clustering is done as follows:

```
import gower
model = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=6, affinity="precomputed", linkage="average")
distance_matrix=gower.gower_matrix(dataframe)
model = model.fit(distance_matrix)
```

After the clustering, I would like to use t-SNE to get a graphical view that helps me to check how is the clustering performing. In order to do this, **I used again the distance matrix as an input parameter for t-SNE**:

```
tsne = TSNE(n_components=2, perplexity=35, metric="precomputed")
df_tsne = tsne.fit_transform(distance_matrix)
```

In the graph shown below, we can see how each cluster is distributed in a 2-D representation (made by t-SNE):

[image: Result of the t-SNE]

My question: **Is this a reliable way of checking the goodness of the clustering?** Thank you in advance!